# Netstream Step method support in red5

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, red5, netstream, streaming-flv-video

[Netstream.step method AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#step%28%29)

This supposedly gives use the ability of frame level control of the video when using a flash media server.

**Question :** Can we implement something like this using the red5 server. Does it support the method?
**Question :** Does red5 have pseudo streaming capability i.e seek to beyond  buffered video ?

This directly from the method description on the adobe docs

> Steps forward or back the specified
>   number of frames, relative to the
>   currently displayed frame. Specify a
>   positive number to step forward and a
>   negative number to step in reverse.
>   Call this method to create accurate
>   fast forward or rewind functionality.
>
> This method is available only when
>   data is streaming from Flash Media
>   Server 3.5.3 or higher and when
>   NetStream.inBufferSeek is true. Also,
>   the target frame must be in the
>   buffer. For example, if the currently
>   displayed frame is frame number 120
>   and you specify a value of 1000, the
>   method fails if frame number 1120 is
>   not in the buffer.
>
> This method is intended to be used
>   with the pause() or togglePause()
>   methods. If you step 10 frames forward
>   or backward during playback without
>   pausing, you may not notice the steps
>   or they'll look like a glitch. Also,
>   when you call pause() or togglePause
>   the audio is suppressed.
>
> If the call to NetStream.step() is
>   successful, a NetStatusEvent is sent
>   with "NetStream.Step.Notify" as the
>   value of the info object's code
>   property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not in Red5 right now but I'll add an enhancement request on the issue tracker. For now you could implement a pause + seek scheme.